# react - json from url not loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code that is returning a blank page and I don't know why.  There's no error but looking in the sources I can see the API data is not loading from the URL. -

```
var WGListList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var wglistNodes = this.props.data.map(function(wglist) {
      return (
        <WGList name={wglist.name} key={wglist.id} />
      );
    });
    return (
      <div className="wglistList">
        {wglistNodes}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var App = React.createClass({
  loadWGListsFromServer: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://server/api/widgetlists/?format=json",
      pollInterval: 2000,
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {data: []};
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.loadWGListsFromServer();
    setInterval(this.loadWGListsFromServer, this.pollInterval);
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="wglistBox">
        <h1>Widget Lists</h1>
        <WGListList data={this.state.data} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var WGList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="wglist">
        <h2 className="wglistName">
          {this.props.name}
        </h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

If I change

```
url: this.props.url,
pollInterval: this props.pollInterval
```

and do this -

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <App url="http://server/api/widgetlists/?format=json" pollInterval={2000} />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

it works.

hmmm... still new to javascript.  Issue seems to be how I'm naming components.  If I change `App` back to `WGListBox` in both instances which is similar to the tutorial it works.  Those are the only two references to that line though, where else is it persisting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so learned the issue is that apparently javascript has issues with beginning variables with lowercass.  I actually had one named `wgApp` later in my code snipped and that was what was breaking it.  I renamed to `WGApp` and worked fine.